# Trying to mask a domain xxx.test.com to point to xxzz.test.com/simple

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

So we have the following two sample domains:

xxx.test.com

and we want to point that to (same ip) this domain:

xxzz.test.com/yyy

and then when you click on a link like so:

xxx.test.com/bbb

it points to:

xxzz.test.com/yyy/bbb

What's the best way to achieve this, DNS, ModRewrite... and how

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` is the way to go here. Use a `RewriteCond` to test if you're in the right subdomain (xxx.test.com), then capture any URI and rewrite to `xxzz.test.com/yyy/<the-URI>`. If you want to mask the call and both servers are running under the same Apache instance, don't include the [R] flag. If you have two different Apache instances, you'll have to proxy between them using the [P] flag, but that will affect performance.

Comment: can you please provide a more specific example as far as the actual code